# JQM add link from function not using click event

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

have a function that creates link if not present (pagination link after fetching new data)

I call function below from controller if total_pages > 1

```
function add_pagination_div() {
    data = '<div id="pagination_sec"><a style="display:block;width:100%;background:#EEEEEE;text-align:center;padding:10px 0;" page-number="1" class="paginate_button" href="#">Show More...</a></div>'
    $(data).appendTo('[data-role=page]').trigger('create');
}
```

It adds it to view, but then click event that is on page will not work.

```
$(".paginate_button").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var pnumb = $(".paginate_button").attr('page-number');
    var newValue = parseInt(pnumb) + 1;
    $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "/app/Place/more?page=" + pnumb + "&requested_action=index&listClass=placeList",
          success: function(){
            $(".paginate_button").attr('page-number', newValue);
          }
     });
});
```

EDIT

---

from controller

```
data = '<div id="pagination_sec"><a style="display:block;width:100%;background:#EEEEEE;text-align:center;padding:10px 0;" data-page-name="index" data-list_name="peopleList" page-number="1" class="paginate_button" href="#">Show More...</a></div>'

WebView.execute_js("add_pagination_div('#{data}');")
```

Then changed script to:

```
function add_pagination_div(linkData) {
    $(linkData).appendTo('[data-role=page]').trigger('create');
    $(".paginate_button").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var pnumb = $(".paginate_button").attr('page-number');
        var newValue = parseInt(pnumb) + 1;
        var pageName = $(".paginate_button").attr('page-name')
        var listName = $(".paginate_button").attr('data-list_name')
        $.ajax({
              type: "GET",
              url: "/app/Place/more?page=" + pnumb + "&requested_action=" + pageName + "&listClass=" + listName,
              success: function(){
                $(".paginate_button").attr('page-number', newValue);
              }
         });
    });
}
```

Comment: Is .click() being called after add_pagination_div()? The order of events might be off; if the click binding is called before the div is created, it won't be bound to anything. I would put .click() in add_pagination_div().

Comment: cmpolis, you are right need to add click to add_pagination_div, but then I need set link form controller since reusing this in different views.  But don't know how to do this.  updated question to show how I'm trying to do this.

Comment: I guess I can just hide / show from controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.live()` or better yet `.delegate()` to bind the click handler to elements that have yet to be added to the dom. So when your `.paginate_button` link is added the click handler will work.

Some documentation for ya:

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

http://api.jquery.com/live/

Here is a jsperf showing that `.delegate()` is less resource intensive than `.live()`: http://jsperf.com/jquery-live-vs-jquery-delegate/15

So `$(".paginate_button").click(function(event){` would change to:

```
$("[data-role=page]").delegate('.paginate_button', 'click', function(event){
```

OR

```
$(".paginate_button").live('click', function(event){
```

Note: it would be better to use the id of the pseudo-page in the delegate call as $('#page_id') is a much faster selector than $('[data-role=page]'). Using the id selector uses the native getElementById() function which is fast and the data-attribute seelctor searches all the elements on the page to see if they have the data-attribute.